# What is the covering number of the unit cube?

Tags: statistics

The $\varepsilon$-**covering number** of the unit cube $[-1,1]^d$ with respect to the infinity norm.
In one dimension, considering the interval [-1,1],equipped with the metric |.|,we divide [-1,1] into L:=$\left( \bigl\lfloor \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\bigr\rfloor + 1 \right)$ sub-intervals.
How about this in d-dimension?I do not know how to devide the interval, or how to prove that the covering number of d-dimensional unit cube is at most $\left( \bigl\lfloor \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\bigr\rfloor + 1 \right)^d$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Isnt the interval $[-1,1]$ divided into $\lfloor 2/\epsilon \rfloor + 1$ intervals?